# Probability Density Question

Tags: probability

> For each value of p>1, let
>
> $c(p)=\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty}\cfrac{1}{x^p}$
>
> Suppose that the random variable X has a discrete distribution with the following pf (probability function:
>
> $f(x) = \cfrac{1}{c(p)x^p}$ for $ x \ge 1$
>
> a.  For each fixed positive integer n, determine the probability that X will be divisible by n.
>
> b.  Determine the probability that X will be odd.

I'm not sure where to start on this question.  Can someone please help?

I want to say that simplifies to f(x)=1.  Is this true?

Also, I'm not sure I understand the question.  Could someone please do an example or something?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: $c(p)=\zeta(p)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N=\left\{ n,2n,3n,\ldots\right\} $ the set of positive integers
divisible by $n$. In a) You are asked to find $P\left\{ X\in N\right\} =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P\left\{ X=kn\right\} $. If you know the probability that $X$ is divisible by 2 then automatically you know the probability that $X$ is not divisible by 2.

Comment: Does f(x)=1?  Because there's 1/xp

Comment: $\Sigma_{x=1}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)=1$

Comment: $P\left\{ X\in N\right\} =\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}f\left(nx\right)=n^{-p}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)$=$n^{-p}$